# Python replace function [replace once]

Tags: python, string, replace

I need help with a program I'm making in Python.

Assume I wanted to replace every instance of the word `"steak"` to `"ghost"` (just go with it...) but I also wanted to replace every instance of the word `"ghost"` to `"steak"` at the same time.  The following code does not work:

```
 s="The scary ghost ordered an expensive steak"
 print s
 s=s.replace("steak","ghost")
 s=s.replace("ghost","steak")
 print s
```

it prints: `The scary steak ordered an expensive steak`

What I'm trying to get is `The scary steak ordered an expensive ghost`

Comment: Do you want `unghosted` to becomes `unsteaked`?  (The example that comes to mind from a question the other week was "name" and "enamel".)

Comment: Hm, but maybe you want `ghosts` to be converted to `steaks` and vice-versa. It's what `.replace` would do.

Comment: Do you want to replace only once?  Or every instance?  You should clarify that portion of your question ... (especially considering the attention it is getting)

Answer (score 25):

I'd probably use a regex here:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "The scary ghost ordered an expensive steak"
>>> sub_dict = {'ghost':'steak','steak':'ghost'}
>>> regex = '|'.join(sub_dict)
>>> re.sub(regex, lambda m: sub_dict[m.group()], s)
'The scary steak ordered an expensive ghost'
```

Or, as a function which you can copy/paste:

```
import re
def word_replace(replace_dict,s):
    regex = '|'.join(replace_dict)
    return re.sub(regex, lambda m: replace_dict[m.group()], s)
```

Basically, I create a mapping of words that I want to replace with other words (`sub_dict`).  I can create a regular expression from that mapping.  In this case, the regular expression is `"steak|ghost"` (or `"ghost|steak"` -- order doesn't matter) and the regex engine does the rest of the work of finding non-overlapping sequences and replacing them accordingly.

---

*Some possibly useful modifications*

- `regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape,replace_dict))` -- Allows the regular expressions to have special regular expression syntax in them (like parenthesis).  This escapes the special characters to make the regular expressions match the literal text.
- `regex = '|'.join(r'\b{0}\b'.format(x) for x in replace_dict)` -- make sure that we don't match if one of our words is a substring in another word.  In other words, change `he` to `she` but not `the` to `tshe`.

Comment: One advantage of using regexes is that you could add boundary markers to help prevent accidental substring matches.  [You could make that work without regexes too, of course.]

Comment: @DSM -- Sure -- And really that just becomes a question of modifying how you join the `sub_dict` here.  Something like:  `'|'.join(r'(?:\b{}\b)'.format(x) for x in regex)` -- if I'm remembering my regex syntax properly :)

Comment: (Oh, and close the quote. :P)

Comment: I suppose that's why I usually test these things in the interactive interpretter.

Comment: I worked out a groupby solution but the way I was doing it didn't extend to handle case mismatches very well. :-/

Comment: New problem: I want to replace the word "he" into "she" but everytime I type "the" it comes back "tshe"

Comment: @user2154113 -- Read the comments above -- Particularly my response to DSM about adding word boundary markers.

Comment: @user2154113 -- Sorry.  That's because I wasn't thinking clearly when I wrote the comment.  It should have been: `regex = '|'.join(r'(?:\b{}\b)'.format(x) for x in sub_dict)`

Comment: Good idea to escape the strings so it doesn't break when someone adds a string with special meaning `regex = '|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in sub_dict)`

Comment: @gnibbler -- Yeah, I thought about that one too.  I figured that I would add that next if the OP needed it, but as a first pass, I wanted to keep it simple :).  Maybe I'll add a modifications section...

Answer (score 13):

Split the string by one of the targets, do the replace, and put the whole thing back together.

```
pieces = s.split('steak')
s = 'ghost'.join(piece.replace('ghost', 'steak') for piece in pieces)
```

This works *exactly* as `.replace()` would, including ignoring word boundaries. So it will turn `"steak ghosts"` into `"ghost steaks"`.

Comment: +1: This has better performance than the regex solution. See my deleted answer

Comment: @Abhijit -- Interesting, but not too surprising that this would be faster than re.sub.  I still like re.sub though ... I find it to be a little more explicit and flexible (e.g. adding word boundaries).  Note that if you really want this to go faster, you could put the stuff in `join` in a list-comp instead of a generator expression.  That is always faster for `.join` ... by stylistically it's uglier.

Comment: @nneonneo -- I guess I should read the source on `''.join` for python3.  On python2, the generator gets turned into a list anyway which is why it's always faster.  But maybe they did something different on python3.x?

Comment: @mgilson: OOPS. Misread the timeit results. I guess DST really messed me up. `.join` is always 10~15% slower if given a genexpr than if it's given a list.

Comment: @nneonneo -- you threw me for a loop for a minute there :).  `join` needs a list so that it can iterate through it twice.  The first iteration figures out what size the output string should be so that it can allocate enough memory.

Comment: @mgilson: I suspected as much, and reading the code confirmed it. Thanks for enlightening me. (Though, I imagine an implementation that doubled the string length on-demand couldn't be *that* slow...but I guess I don't know.)

Comment: @nneonneo -- Yeah.  I suppose that is akin to how python `list` and `dict` objects are implemented ... I suppose if you're really good at C, you could give it a try and see :)

Comment: @Abhijit I’m not really convinced by one-off microbenchmarks if they don’t show a very convincing, consistent difference across many different cases. Your benchmark actually looks quite good but there are plenty of opportunities for mistakes in microbenchmarks. Furthermore, assuming a solid regex implementation this result isn’t all that plausible: `split`ting requires a lot more memory allocations than a properly implemented regex engine, and the regular expression here is trivial and can be executed very efficiently – *as* efficient, in fact, as the work `split` has to perform.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I rewrote my answer to consider different variation of data.

Comment: @nneonneo: This version does outperform other versions and can be considered to be equally Robust. Check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Rename one of the words to a temp value that doesn't occur in the text.  Note this wouldn't be the most efficient way for a very large text.  For that a `re.sub` might be more appropriate.

```
 s="The scary ghost ordered an expensive steak"
 print s
 s=s.replace("steak","temp")
 s=s.replace("ghost","steak")
 S=s.replace("temp","steak")
 print s
```

Comment: But say I wanted to have a user input for it, is there anyway to ensure they don't use the temp value WITHOUT making the temp value a random series of letters like "zxdasd"?

Comment: @user2154113 you can first check if the value is in the string. Anyway, this is the *wrong* way of doing it. The right way is Leif Andersen's.

Comment: And how does Leif's answer replace every instance if there is more than one instance?  This way actually works.

Comment: This works but requires shifty temporary values. (You can use some random Unicode to reduce the risk, but it is not a very general solution).

Comment: The temp value can be anything, even unprintable bytes like `\x01`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Yeah, but generally you wish it that the temp was something that could not possibly exist in a string (i.e. it should be out-of-band).

Comment: Only the user can know. It could work fine for the domain.  For something more robust I'd use a regex and do it in one pass.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I rewrote your implementation to make it a bit robust (Check my answer). I have also timed it and have performance comparable to using nneonneo's version though the performance is not consistent across different types of  test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use the count variable in the `string.replace()` method.  So using your code, you wouold have:

```
s="The scary ghost ordered an expensive steak"
print s
s=s.replace("steak","ghost", 1)
s=s.replace("ghost","steak", 1)
print s
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: This would work, but only for this specific example.  If there were more instances of the words or even if the words were in a different order it wouldn't work.

Comment: True, but since we weren't given any other context for why the words wanted to be changed, this is the best way to do it. But yes, if he did want a more robust solution, than this won't work.

Comment: +1 for being the only "replace once". All other answers solve the general case of swapping X,Y in a string, but yours answers the question.

Comment: @RyanAmos -- "replace once" is in the title, but if you read the body of the question it says "every instance" ...

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this? Store the original in a split list, then have a translation dict. Keeps your core code short, then just adjust the dict when you need to adjust the translation. Plus, easy to port to a function:

```
 def translate_line(s, translation_dict):
    line = []
    for i in s.split():
       # To take account for punctuation, strip all non-alnum from the
       # word before looking up the translation.
       i = ''.join(ch for ch in i if ch.isalnum()]
       line.append(translation_dict.get(i, i))
    return ' '.join(line)


 >>> translate_line("The scary ghost ordered an expensive steak", {'steak': 'ghost', 'ghost': 'steak'})
 'The scary steak ordered an expensive ghost'
```

Comment: +1 for the idea, but you're not quite there yet. This only works if there is no punctuation.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yah, definitely not a robust solution :) You could probably strip all non-alphanumeric characters from the word and then use that for translation .. I'll adjust

Answer (score 1):

**Note** Considering the viewership of this Question, I undeleted and rewrote it for different types of test cases

I have considered four competing implementations from the answers

```
>>> def sub_noregex(hay):
    """
    The Join and replace routine which outpeforms the regex implementation. This
    version uses generator expression
    """
    return 'steak'.join(e.replace('steak','ghost') for e in hay.split('ghost'))

>>> def sub_regex(hay):
    """
    This is a straight forward regex implementation as suggested by @mgilson
    Note, so that the overheads doesn't add to the cummulative sum, I have placed
    the regex creation routine outside the function
    """
    return re.sub(regex,lambda m:sub_dict[m.group()],hay)

>>> def sub_temp(hay, _uuid = str(uuid4())):
    """
    Similar to Mark Tolonen's implementation but rather used uuid for the temporary string
    value to reduce collission
    """
    hay = hay.replace("steak",_uuid).replace("ghost","steak").replace(_uuid,"steak")
    return hay

>>> def sub_noregex_LC(hay):
    """
    The Join and replace routine which outpeforms the regex implementation. This
    version uses List Comprehension
    """
    return 'steak'.join([e.replace('steak','ghost') for e in hay.split('ghost')])
```

A generalized timeit function

```
>>> def compare(n, hay):
    foo = {"sub_regex": "re",
           "sub_noregex":"",
           "sub_noregex_LC":"",
           "sub_temp":"",
           }
    stmt = "{}(hay)"
    setup = "from __main__ import hay,"
    for k, v in foo.items():
        t = Timer(stmt = stmt.format(k), setup = setup+ ','.join([k, v] if v else [k]))
        yield t.timeit(n)
```

And the generalized test routine

```
>>> def test(*args, **kwargs):
    n = kwargs['repeat']
    print "{:50}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}".format("Test Case", "sub_temp",
                             "sub_noregex ", "sub_regex",
                             "sub_noregex_LC ")
    for hay in args:
        hay, hay_str = hay
        print "{:50}{:15.10}{:15.10}{:15.10}{:15.10}".format(hay_str, *compare(n, hay))
```

And the Test Results are as follows

```
>>> test((' '.join(['steak', 'ghost']*1000), "Multiple repeatation of search key"),
         ('garbage '*998 + 'steak ghost', "Single repeatation of search key at the end"),
         ('steak ' + 'garbage '*998 + 'ghost', "Single repeatation of at either end"),
         ("The scary ghost ordered an expensive steak", "Single repeatation for smaller string"),
         repeat = 100000)
Test Case                                            sub_temp     sub_noregex      sub_regex   sub_noregex_LC 
Multiple repeatation of search key                   0.2022748797   0.3517142003   0.4518992298   0.1812594258
Single repeatation of search key at the end          0.2026047957   0.3508259952   0.4399926194   0.1915298898
Single repeatation of at either end                  0.1877455356   0.3561734007   0.4228843986   0.2164233388
Single repeatation for smaller string                0.2061019057   0.3145984487   0.4252060592   0.1989413449
>>>
```

Based on the Test Result

1. Non Regex LC and the temp variable substitution have better performance though the performance of the usage of temp variable is not consistent
2. LC version has better performance compared to generator (confirmed)
3. Regex is more than two times slower (so if the piece of code is a bottleneck then the implementation change can be reconsidered)
4. The Regex and non regex versions are equivalently Robust and can scale

Comment: Hmm. I have to admit that I’m puzzled by that. All the non-regex versions perform many more memory allocations. This *should* be the performance-limiting step. Have you tried pre-compiling the regular expression? Do you know which regular expression engine Python is using? (I’m also appalled that list comprehension is (so much!) faster than generator expressions. Looks like a serious weakness in CPython.)