# TypeError when using replace() from dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, int, typeerror

First of all: Please keep in mind that I'm very much a beginner at programming.

I'm trying to write a simple program in Python that will replace the consonants in a string with consonant+"o"+consonant. For example "b" would be replaced with "bob" and "d" would be replaced with "dod" (so the word "python" would be changed to "popytothohonon").

To do this I created a dictionary, that contained the pairs b:bob,c:coc,d:dod etc. Then I used the replace() command to read through the word and replace the consonants with their translation in the dictionary. The full piece of code looks like this:

```
def replacer(text):
    consonant='bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
    lexicon={}
    for x in range(0,len(consonant)):
        lexicon[x]=(consonant[x]),(consonant[x]+'o'+consonant[x])
    for i,j in lexicon.items():
        text=(text.replace(i,j))
    return text
```

Now, when I try to call this function I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\x\x.py", line 37, in <module> 
      print(replacer("python"))
  File "D:\x\x.py", line 17, in replacer 
      text=(text.replace(i,j))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

But I'm not using any ints! There's got to be something wrong with the dictionary, because everything works when i make it "by hand" like this:

```
list={'b':'bob', 'c':'coc', 'd':'dod', 'f':'fof', 'g':'gog', 'h':'hoh'......}
```

But when I print the "non-hand-made" dictionary everything seems to be in order:

```
{0: ('b', 'bob'), 1: ('c', 'coc'), 2: ('d', 'dod'), 3: ('f', 'fof')........
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lexicon` is a dictionary with integers as keys and tuples as values.  when you iterate over it's items, you're getting tuples of the form `(integer,tuple)`.  You're then passing that integer and tuple to `text.replace` as `i` and `j` which is why it's complaining.  Perhaps you meant:

```
 for i,j in lexicon.values():
     ...
```

For this simple replacement, `str.replace` is fine, but for more complicated replacements, the code will probably be more robust (and possibly execute faster!) if you [use `re.sub` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15324369/748858).

---

Also, as pointed out in the comments, for this case, a better data structure would be to use a `list`:

```
lexicon = [ (x,'{0}o{0}'.format(x)) for x in chars ]
```

Now you can build your dict from this list if you really want:

```
lexicon = dict(enumerate(lexicon))
```

but there's probably no need.  And in this case, you'd iterate over `lexicon` directly:

```
for i,j in lexicon:
    ...
```

If you're only going to do this once, you could even do it lazily without ever materializing the list by using a generator expression:

```
lexicon = ( (x,'{0}o{0}'.format(x)) for x in chars )
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for dictionaries this time, just iterate over characters of text, add vovels or consonant+o+consonant to an result array and join it to a string at the end:

```
def replacer(text):
    consonants = set('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz')
    result = []
    for c in text:
        if c in consonants:
            result.append(c+"o"+c)
        else:
            result.append(c)
    return "".join(result)

print(replacer("python"))
```

---

For advanced users:

```
def replacer(text):
    return re.sub(r"[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]", r"\g<0>o\g<0>", text)
```

---

And to answer "What am I doing wrong?" - dictionaries are useful for arbitrary keys, usually `list.append()` is preferred from using keys 0-n in a dict. And since you are not interested in a consonant's position, you can iterate over strings directly like this:

```
for x in consonant:
    lexicon[x] = x+"o"+x
```

Comment: In this case, you're better off making `consonants` a `set`.

Comment: @mgilson true. i just didn't see generator expressions like `set(c for c in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz")` as "very-much-beginner" stuff

Comment: `set(c for c in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz")`?  Why not `set('bcd..')`, which seems pretty comprehensible?

Comment: @DSM oh right, i forgot sets can be created from string too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you wanted to achieve is lexicon mapping consonant to replacement. It may be done this way:

```
lexicon = { c: c+'o'+c for c in consonant }
```

which is equivalent of:

```
for c in consonant:
  lexicon[c] = c+'o'+c
```

Answer (score -1):

no ... your keys in the handmade version are strings ... your kets in the other version are ints ... ints have no replace method

Comment: Yeah, I mixed up keys and values.