# replacing word with another word from the string in python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a string: `"y, i agree with u."`

And I have array dictionary `[(word_will_replace, [word_will_be_replaced])]`:

`[('yes', ['y', 'ya', 'ye']), ('you', ['u', 'yu'])]`

i want to replace ***'y' with 'yes'*** and ***'u' with 'you'*** according to the array dictionary.

So the result i want: `"yes, i agree with you."`

I want to keep the punctuation there.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516623/replacing-substrings-given-a-dictionary-of-strings-to-be-replaced-as-keys-and-re/16516892#16516892

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/reference.html The `\b` meta character matches on word boundaries, as in, between a word and space or word and symbol. e.g. `\by\b` will match ONLY the word `y` on its own.

Comment: Both solutions below are correct under the assumption that the replacement word is not a word to be replaced for another word. e.g. `{abc <-- ab, abcd <-- abc}`. If you don't have this assumption, then only jamylak's solution is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
s="y, i agree with u. yu."
l=[('yes', ['y', 'ya', 'ye']), ('you', ['u', 'yu'])] 
d={ k : "\\b(?:" + "|".join(v) + ")\\b" for k,v in l}
for k,r in d.items(): s = re.sub(r, k, s)  
print s
```

**Output**

```
yes, i agree with you. you.
```

Comment: This is a good example.  If you're going to do this over and over again, it might be worthwhile to store the dictionary as `key:re.compile(...)`

Comment: how I can make d={'yes': ['y', 'ya', 'ye'],'you': ['u', 'yu']}

from the array [('yes', ['y', 'ya', 'ye']), ('you', ['u', 'yu'])] 

??

Comment: @mgilson that is superfluous, as compiling and caching regexes is already built into the re module.

Answer (score 2):

Extending @gnibbler's answer from [Replacing substrings given a dictionary of strings-to-be-replaced as keys and replacements as values. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516623/replacing-substrings-given-a-dictionary-of-strings-to-be-replaced-as-keys-and-re/16516892#16516892) with the tips implemented from Raymond Hettinger in the comments.

```
import re
text = "y, i agree with u."
replacements = [('yes', ['y', 'ya', 'ye']), ('you', ['u', 'yu'])]
d = {w: repl for repl, words in replacements for w in words}
def fn(match):
    return d[match.group()]

print re.sub('|'.join(r'\b{0}\b'.format(re.escape(k)) for k in d), fn, text)
```

---

```
>>> 
yes, i agree with you.
```

Comment: @perreal no since those aren't captured

Answer (score 0):

That's not a dictionary -- it's a list, but it could be converted to a `dict` pretty easily.  In this case, however, I would make it a little more explicit:

```
d = {}
replacements = [('yes', ['y', 'ya', 'ye']), ('you', ['u', 'yu'])]
for value,words in replacements:
    for word in words:
        d[word] = value
```

Now you have the dictionary mapping responses to what you want to replace them with:

```
{'y':'yes', 'ya':'yes', 'ye':'yes',...}
```

once you have that, you can pop in my answer from here using regular expressions:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15324369/748858

Comment: Sorry,

when I want to replace: "You"

there become: "Yesou"