# Replace whole word Python (only variable)

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to do a code which replace only whole word in string variable.First of all I found `re.sub` solution but there was no mentioned about variable inside. 
Now my solution looks (it does not replace whole word):

```
for index in (range(len(lista)):
    query=query.replace(lista[index],var)
```

As on example above, I want to replace value in `lista[index]` with value from `VAR -> variable`.

EDIT:

Example query:

```
Select Information,AdditionalInformation,Price from Table
```

example lista vales:

```
Information, Price
```

example var:

```
var = "hide"
```

Finally query should looks:

```
Select hide,AdditionalInformation,hide from Table
```

Comment: what query contains? What exactly you have to replace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replacing word with another word from the string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600823/replacing-word-with-another-word-from-the-string-in-python)

Comment: not related but you can simplify your block like so: `for elem in lista:
    query=query.replace(elem,var)`

Comment: `re.sub()` offers a function as replacement - here you can include anything you want.

Answer (score 7):

I think this should work:

```
for word in alist:
    query = re.sub(r'\b'+word+r'\b',var,query)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compile a regex that matches any of the words in `lista`.

```
import re

query = "Select Information,AdditionalInformation,Price from Table"
lista = ["Information", "Price"]
var = "hide"

pat = re.compile(r'\b' + '|'.join(lista) + r'\b')
query = pat.sub(var, query)
print(query)
```

**output**

```
Select hide,AdditionalInformation,hide from Table
```

The `\b` is used to match word boundaries; this prevents "AdditionalInformation" from being modified. See [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the docs. We need to write it as a raw string, `r'\b'`, otherwise it gets interpreted as the ANSI escape code for backspace.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace value in lista[index] with value from VAR ->
>   variable.

From this, I *think* you're looking for something along these lines:

```
for index in (range(len(lista))):
    lista[index] = var
```

This changes all the items in the list to `var`.

If you don't want all items in the list to be replaced, you would need to make a decision to replace the correct item, and so maybe (if you already know the position of the item in the list that needs replacing):

```
lista[index] = var
```

Comment: Look at the examples (they may have been added after you started this).

Answer (score 0):

As kaasias wrote, just change the the elements of the list with this code:

```
for index in (range(len(lista))):
    lista[index] = var
```

and make sure you create your query with the new elements of the list.

```
query = "SELECT " + lista[0] + ", " + AdditionalInformation + ", " lista[1] + " FROM " + table
```