# Replacing words in a list occuring in a text with words in another list

Tags: python

```
position_list = ['front', 'frnt', 'ft', 'back', 'bck', 'behind', 'right', 'rhs']

position = ['down', 'right', 'inner', 'front', 'top', 'back', 'left']
```

These are the two lists I'm working on in PYTHON.
For a given text if any of the words in position_list occurs, it must be replaced with  specific words in position.

i.e text is : "The frnt tyre and bck tyre are worn out"

The 'frnt' and 'bck' must be replaced with 'front' and 'back' respectively.

The python code I used is:

```
if wrong == 'frnt' or wrong == 'ft':
```

str = str.replace(wrong,'front')

```
if wrong == 'bck' or wrong == 'behind':
```

str = str.replace(wrong,'back')

But I'm looking for python codes which directly replaces words using these lists.

Comment: Why should `frnt` be replaced with `front` and not `right`?

Comment: If you create a dictionary mapping position_list words to position values, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15324369/748858) could be very helpful.

Comment: Anyway.I just gave an example. I want to replace the words with the specific word I need.

Comment: your example is really unclear, and is too much open to interpretation. I don't get what's your `position` list for, how you imagine you can make an algorithm that can guess that in a same list the word `front` have to be replaced with the two following words `frnt` and `ft` whereas the `back` word has to be replace with the single word `bck`.

Comment: I guess what you're actually looking for is a spelling corrector, in which case you might want to have a look at this [classic script](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get where you're heading with those two lists structure. It's unclear, and I don't think you can get a proper algorithm out of that.

You say: "For a given text if any of the words in position_list occurs, it must be replaced with specific words in position", that means that '*front*' has to be replaced by '*down*', '*frnt*' by '*right*' and '*rhs*' has no replacement. That makes no sense!

So I'm guessing, from the rest of your question, that you want the words that follows '*front*' to be replaced by '*front*', and the words that follows '*back*' to be replaced by '*back*'. But then, there's no information to help an algorithm know what words are the replacements, and what words are to be replaced.

So the only solution would be to change your structures in a more pythonic way to make an easy and elegant algorithm out of it. Then, you may want to try with a structure like this:

```
position = ['front', 'back']
position_list = [('frnt', 'ft'), ('bck')]
```

and then the algorithm would look like:

```
replaces = zip(position, position_list)
for new_word, old_words in replaces:
    for old_word in old_words:
        str = str.replace(old_word, new_word)
```

You can also use a dictionary:

```
positions = {'front': ['frnt', 'ft'], 'back': ['bck']}
for new_word, old_words in positions.iteritems():
    for old_word in old_words:
        str = str.replace(old_word, new_word)
```

In other words, try avoiding creating structures that would lead in the end making an algorithm dealing with indexes of the list...

Comment: is it possible that for string "please drive 2 km ft after next cross" your solution will not work?

Comment: not sure if that's what you're spotting, but I just corrected the solution, I carelessly interverted the indexes in the outer for while writing it ;-)

Comment: "please drive 2 km **ft** a **ft** er next cross"

Comment: @oleg - I got 'please drive 2 km *front* a *front* er next cross' :)

Comment: is this expected? I mean afronter in result

Comment: For me it is wrong result. I think OP didn't expect that kind of problem using `replace()`. +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of mapping between your two lists, otherwise you can't figure out what to replace with what. You could use a dict:

```
t = 'The frnt tyre'

words = {
    'front': ('frnt', 'frt'),
}

for word, repl in words.items():
    for r in repl:
        t = t.replace(r, word)

print t
```

Result:

```
The front tyre
```

Answer (score -1):

I think with sting.replace() method,(maybe)will replace substrings you don't want to replace as @oleg indicated

I know that this isn't the cleaner method but perhaps the use of a dictionary and .split() and .join() would help.

```
s = 'the frt bck behind'
l = s.split()
new =[]
d ={'frt':'front','behind':'back','bck':'back'}
for word in l:
    if word in d:
        new.append(d[word])
    else:new.append(word)    
print " ".join(new)
>>> the front back back
```

i suppose that there will be issues with caps and lower and punctuation but it is easy to work it out with a couple of string.replace()s